# Jump Discontinuities Of A Function

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Prove that a function can only have at most countable points of jump discontinuities.
$$$$Consider a function $f(x)$. Now consider the set $$E_n =(c : |\lim_{x \to c^-}f(x)-\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)|>\frac{1}{n})$$. Let us chose a $c \in E_n$ then we claim that $c$ is an isolated point of $E_n$. Suppose this is not true then for every $k$ there exists a $$c_k \in (c-\frac{1}{k}, c+\frac{1}{k})$$, such that $$|\lim_{x \to (c_ k)^-}f(x)-\lim_{x \to (c_ k)^+}f(x)|>\frac{1}{n}$$. Now as we can see $c_k$ converges to $c$ and hence infinitely many members of $c_k$ lie on either left or the right of $c$, so WLOG let us assume that infinitely many members of $c_k$ lie to the right side of $c$. Now as $c \in E_n$ so let $$\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)=L_1$$, then for $\epsilon =\frac{1}{3n}$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x, y \in (c, c+\delta)$ we have $$|f(x)-f(y)|<\frac{1}{3n}$$. Also as $c_k$ converges to $c$, so there exists a $K$ such that for all $k > K$ we have $$c_k \in (c, c+\delta)$$. Now chose a $k_0>K$ such that $$c_{k_0} \in (c, c+\delta)$$. Now as $c_{k_0} \in E_n$ so we can chose a $x_0<c_{k_0}$ and $x_0 \in (c, c+\delta)$ such that $$|f(x_0)-\lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^-}f(x)|<\frac{1}{3n}$$, similarly we can chose a $y_0>c_{k_0}$ and $y_0 \in (c, c+\delta)$ such that $$|f(y_0)-\lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^+}f(x)|<\frac{1}{3n}$$. Now consider $$\frac{1}{n} < |\lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^+}f(x) - \lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^-}f(x)| \leq |\lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^+}f(x)-f(y_0)| + |f(y_0)-f(x_0)| + |f(x_0) - \lim_{x \to (c_{k_0})^-}f(x)| < \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{3n} + \frac{1}{3n} = \frac{1}{n}$$, a contradiction. Hence every point in $E_n$ is an isolated point and hence $E_n$ is a countable set. Also all the points at which $f(x)$ has a Jump discontinuity is covered by the sets $E_n$ where $n$ varies over all the natural numbers. And hence the set of points of jump discontinuities of $f(x)$ is countable.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is monotone? Otherwise $\lim_{x \to c^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)$ do not necessarily exist.

Comment: No i am not assuming that $f(x)$ is monotone and $E_n$ is the set of points $c$ where bot LHL and RHL exists and satisfy the inequality, so $\lim_{x \to c^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)$ both exists if $c \in E_n$